# How to use pythons UIAutomator to get all items of a listbox when some are not shown on the screen

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

How do you use Python and UIAutomator to

1. count the number of a given item on the entire page(not just shown)
2. cycle through them to check information.

In my case I have a list of calls containing some data, and I want to test the number of calls displayed is correct, and to search for particular numbers in the list.
the following exerpt are the repeating nodes I want to verify the count (to make sure it wont go over 100) and then search for partiular calls.

```
    <node index="4" text="" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/fragment_recent_list_view" class="android.widget.ListView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[11,193][789,1145]">
      <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[11,193][789,301]">
        <node index="0" text="1002" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_name" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[86,204][432,247]" />
        <node index="1" text="11/07 08:40" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_date" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[432,204][778,247]" />
        <node index="2" text="00:00:00" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_duration" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[184,247][778,290]" />
      </node>
      <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[11,302][789,410]">
        <node index="0" text="1004" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_name" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[86,313][432,356]" />
        <node index="1" text="11/07 08:40" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_date" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[432,313][778,356]" />
        <node index="2" text="00:00:00" resource-id="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_duration" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.myd.dialer" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[184,356][778,399]" />
      </node>
      ...
    </node>
```

I can do :

```
listViewObj = dev(resourceIdMatches="com.myd.dialer:id/fragment_recent_list_view")
listViewObj.fling.toEnd()  #will scroll to end of list
print("listViewObj count = ".format(str(listViewObj.count)))    # this is 0?
# get name objects
objs = dev(resourceIdMatches="com.myd.dialer:id/list_item_recent_text_view_name")
cnt = objs.count      # giving 9 not 99 or 100 etc (9 can show on the screen)
print("obs count = {}".format(str(cnt)))
for o in objs:
    print("{}".format(o.info['text']))  # will print text item
```

But this will only give me the count (and print) only those items on the screen.
How do I get access to the whole list?

Thank you!

Comment: I have a 'solution' but not a great one.  Very slow, and expects particular data.  However, if I order the items in the listbox I can get the first item, fling to the last item (to remember them)  I can then go back to the top and get the last item displayed and then add or subtract one from that number and scroll to the new number. (example Call0001-Call0009 displayed so scroll to Call0010).  Meanwhile keeping track of every unique item displayed as to it being visited.  Stop when after a scroll down, there are no new items added.

Comment: However this is very slow as for each scrollToText goes to the top and scrolls back down a page at a time.  (example 100 items in listBox, looking at last page it has to scroll up 8 times, then scroll down 9 times etc.)    It will not work unless all items are unique and in order.  I was hoping to find something more effective than this.